# How to delete sample data?

Tags: contacts

When I accepted sample data on install I did not realize there would be 200 contacts added with no clear way to get rid of them. How do I delete these contacts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The quickest way is to:

- Run a contribution search with no criteria. You will have a result page with all of them.
- For the *Select Records* option, choose **All Records**.
- For the *Actions* option, choose **Delete Contributions**.
- Repeat for contacts with Advanced Search; type "Sample Data" into the "Contact Source" field to find all sample contacts and then bulk delete them. This will cascade down to delete events, activities, etc. You'll also get a message that your own record can't be deleted, so there's no concern about wiping yourself out of the system.

Comment: I got this warning too "The following contacts had been sharing addresses with a contact you just deleted. Their addressses will no longer be shared, but have not been removed or altered."

Answer (score 3):

First delete all test contributions following [Nicholai's answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/5002/4).

Then do an "Advanced Search" and type "Sample Data" into the "Contact Source" field. You can then select all results (should be exactly 200 of them) and bulk-delete them.

Comment: Can you delete the contacts without first deleting contributions? I thought it would throw that error about having "financial transactions" and abort the process.

Comment: Yes, I've modified both our answers now, and yours is the more complete.