# Remove sample data from installation

Tags: installation, delete

I've searched for the answer to this and haven't found it. I'm setting up a brand-new installation of CiviCRM into Wordpress. When installing, I chose to upload all of the sample data. Now that I'm getting the system going, I'm finding the sample data is cluttering up my choices, etc.

Is there a way to completely delete all of the sample data at this point?

I'm a Civi-newbee, so please be gentle with any explanations.

Comment: I don't believe so and I think this question will be marked as a duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/how-to-delete-sample-data unless you can explain what the nuance is here